# Integrating Telegram bot with jenkins

Tags: jenkins, telegram-bot

I want a telegram message from jenkins whenever there is a new build.
I tried integrating telegram bot with jenkins by referring the jenkins plugin documentation :  https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Telegram+Notification+Plugin
But this did not work. Is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: could you explain what did not work?

Comment: I think you need to start with creating a bot: https://core.telegram.org/bots

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can just add step to execute shell script and send message via curl:

```
$ curl -s -X POST https://api.telegram.org/bot[TOKENID]/sendMessage -d chat_id=[ID] -d text="your message"
```

where `[TOKENID]` is your token id, and `[ID]` your chat id.

And your telegram-bot must started by user(or added to chat).

Comment: @SACDES, if my answer solved your problem, please mark my answer as correct. Thank you too.

Comment: Hi @sergey , This worked for me. thank you

Comment: but how to define, if build was success or fail?

Comment: @Shamsiddin On success, the sent Message is returned. For details see: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage